# Why do people post their captchas publicly? Captcha: somerandomword

Tags: security, web, captcha

I'm implementing a website with a CAPTCHA on the registration form; my first. I've read dozens of posts on the arguments for and against, and of all the various implementations out there. I'm happy with all that but it's a necessary evil in my case.

What I don't understand is why people post the random captcha characters in their posts, all over the web? Here's an example from today on [TDWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/The-Next-Big-Thing,-The-Best-Interview,--Too-Primitive-for-COBOL.aspx). In 95 comments, 5 people have appended strings like this to the end of their posts:

> Captcha: nimis.
>   Captcha: augue.
>   Captcha: distineo.

Is this a security risk? Are they publishing the captcha strings so that they can be harvested and used in an attack? Or are they just trying to track themselves by embedding a random word for a subsequent Google search?

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just part of TDWTF culture, sometimes the captchas are made into jokes.

Answer (score 4):

It looks more to me like they simply find the random words funny.